# Can I use PostgreSQL on a server for users to access a desktop application without sharing my source code?

Tags: mit, bsd

I have a desktop application with a login where data users are loaded from a PostgreSQL database in a server on the web. This server has a website where the user can create an account and buy a license for the desktop application.

Am I required to share the desktop application source code for free in order to use PostgreSQL?

PostgreSQL license: https://www.postgresql.org/about/licence/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your desktop applications does not use any open source projects other than PostgreSQL, **you are not required to release the source code** of your desktop application. However, you are required to provide the following text along with your Desktop application.

From https://www.postgresql.org/about/licence/:

> Portions Copyright (c) 1996-2017, The PostgreSQL Global Development
>   Group
>
> Portions Copyright (c) 1994, The Regents of the University of
>   California
>
> Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this software and its
>   documentation for any purpose, without fee, and without a written
>   agreement is hereby granted, provided that the above copyright notice
>   and this paragraph and the following two paragraphs appear in all
>   copies.
>
> IN NO EVENT SHALL THE UNIVERSITY OF CALIFORNIA BE LIABLE TO ANY PARTY
>   FOR DIRECT, INDIRECT, SPECIAL, INCIDENTAL, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES,
>   INCLUDING LOST PROFITS, ARISING OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE AND
>   ITS DOCUMENTATION, EVEN IF THE UNIVERSITY OF CALIFORNIA HAS BEEN
>   ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
>
> THE UNIVERSITY OF CALIFORNIA SPECIFICALLY DISCLAIMS ANY WARRANTIES,
>   INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
>   MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. THE SOFTWARE
>   PROVIDED HEREUNDER IS ON AN "AS IS" BASIS, AND THE UNIVERSITY OF
>   CALIFORNIA HAS NO OBLIGATIONS TO PROVIDE MAINTENANCE, SUPPORT,
>   UPDATES, ENHANCEMENTS, OR MODIFICATIONS.

Edit: If your desktop application doesn't include any PostgreSQL software (i.e. all PostgreSQL software is on the server side), then you are not required to give attribution or licensing information. It might be polite to mention your server is using it, but it is definitely not required in this scenario.